# Honeycomb 3.1 / Mono for Android persist 'LightsOut'

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, xamarin.android

I developed my app using Mono for Android. I have the latest version 4.0.3. My AndroidManifest.xml specifies:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

The app runs on tablets, so in Honeycomb I need to hide the status bar at the bottom of the screen. This is how I do that (with a simple extension method):

```
internal static void LightsOut(this View view)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr view_setSystemUiVisibility = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(view.Class.Handle, "setSystemUiVisibility", "(I)V");
                JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(view.Handle, view_setSystemUiVisibility, new JValue(1));
            }
            catch 
            { }
        }
```

I call this on every view that I instantiate. On my Motorola Xoom, running 3.0.1, this works *great*.

On my Samsung Galaxy Tab running 3.1, it works; but the status bar comes back after some short period of time. In the Android Log I see that LightsOn() is getting called...

How can I prevent the status bar from coming back in 3.1? I saw this event:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

And thought I could use it to hide the status bar, if it comes back. But I don't see how I can subscribe to it (it doesn't show in Intellisense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something specific happen before the status bar comes back, or is it solely time related? A quick search of the [ICS source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/tablet/TabletStatusBar.java#L1131) suggests that the status bar status will be reset when the top App Window changes. Are you calling `StartActivity()` or moving to another app when you see this behavior?

The `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` interface has been bound as the [View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Views.View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener) interface and through the [View.SystemUiVisibilityChange](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aAndroid.Views.View.SystemUiVisibilityChange) event. However, both of these mechanisms require that your `$(TargetFrameworkVersion)` target Android v3.1 or later, which would set your `//uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion` attribute to `12`, and is thus something you (presumably) don't want to do.

I see two plausible solutions here:

1. Figure out why `LightsOn()` is being invoked and try to work around it (call `LightsOut()` within every `Activity.OnCreate()` method?).
2. Provide two versions of your app, one with a `minSdkVersion` of `8`, and one of (at least) `12`, and then use [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) to include both in your program. The device will then run the appropriate package, permitting access to the `View.SystemUiVisibilityChange` event.

Comment: Thank you. The app only has a single activity, but views are regularly brought to the front. Doing this in 3.1 causes the status bar to reshow, apparently, as per your link. I simply call 'LightsOut' again immediately after 'BringToFront' and that solves it.